# Constraint solving differences in sets

Tags: c++, solver, constraint-programming

I have a set of five sets of tuples (int myInt, float myFloat)

I am looking to scale each set uniformly so that it:

**Maximizes the number of occuraces where the difference between the pair of myInts AND the pair of myFloats is near 0, between all set-to-set pairings of tuples in all sets.**

**It then scale all sets to minimize the distances of those pairing of near tuplets**

So input sets 
[ (24, .56), (0, .55) ] 
 
[ (22, .37), (23, .59) ]

Two tuplets are near each other and they should scale to minimize the difference in their float values, ignoring outlying tuplets.

In actual use there are 20 tuplets in each set and between 2 and 20 sets, though usually around 4.

I am new to constraint solving, but the approach that came to mind was.

Give each set a random scaling and then adjust each up or down to maximize the number of near-0 myFloats.  Repeat many times with different random values.

Are there any known approaches for this kind of problem?  Am I on the right track?